# GraphQL : share the context among all the resolvers

Tags: graphql, authorization, apollo-server, resolver

I am implementing Authorization in `GraphQL`. I am storing authorization status in context and want to share it with every resolver. I know that the Apollo server has a context which is shared across all the resolvers i.e  :

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ event, context, appId, userId }) => {
  .... 
   return { event, context, appId, userId };
}
})
```

But my problem is , I want to update the context in different files and other resolver should always have the updated context.
is there any way we can create the context in such way that the changes made in the `context` object is always reflected to other resolvers??

Comment: the same object instance, then why not reflected?

Comment: @xadm will this be reflected ? I am looking for something like React context.

Comment: just test it? try to prove it won't